# Variable de objecto no establecida - Libreoffice

Tags: excel, macros, libreoffice-calc

Tengo una macro que consiste en sumar los valores de la celda según su color de fondo. Pero el fichero en concreto, al abrirlo me da el siguiente error.

**Error de BASIC, variable de objeto no establecida**

Cabe decir que la macro funciona correctamente, solo me salta el error al abrir el archivo, pero es tedioso ya que salta 5/6 veces que de dar a aceptar cada vez que abro el archivo.

Os dejo el código de la macro a continuación.

```
Function SUMARCOLOR(CeldaColor As String, RangoSuma As String) As Double
Dim oRango As Object
Dim oCelda As Double
Dim c As Integer
Dim f As Integer
Dim oCuenta as DOUBLE
oCuenta = 0
oRango = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
oCelda = oRango.GetCellRangeByName(CeldaColor).CellBackColor
oRango = oRango.GetCellRangeByName(RangoSuma)
For c = 0 to oRango.Columns.Count - 1
For f = 0 to oRango.Rows.Count - 1
 If    oRango.GetCellByPosition(c,f).CellBackColor = oCelda Then
     oCuenta = oCuenta+ oRango.GetCellByPosition(c,f).value
  End If
 Next
Next
SUMARCOLOR = oCuenta
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está aquí:

```
oRango = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
```

Al abrirlo, no hay ningún `ActiveSheet`. En lugar, debe ser así:

```
oRango = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByIndex(0)
```

Comment: Para más información: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37240

Comment: Perfecto era eso, es la primera macro que hago.